# Remove specific number of digits using sed

Tags: linux, sed

```
John, 1234567
Bob, 2839211
Alex, 2817821
Mary, 9371281
```

I am currently trying to retrieve the first column with the last 4 digits of the second column using sed, so the output should look like this:

```
John, 4567
Bob, 9211
Alex, 7821
Mary, 1281
```

This is my command: `'s/\(.*,\)\(.*\)//'`, I think that this command matches the first column until the comma and the second column until the end, but I am unsure on how to continue.

Comment: there should be a line break after each name, number and the command should have an asterisk inside both the parentheses my apologies

Comment: Is the file expected to have more columns? Or the format will always be `<text>, <number>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk it works thanks a lot, my apologies I am still very new to this, the format is always text and then number

Comment: @Pyrous please clarify if you always have **space** character after the `,` character

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/^\([^,]*\), *[0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/\1, \2/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/xKWLDO).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\([^,]*\)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a comma
- `, *` - a comma and zero or more spaces
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `\([0-9]\{4\}\)` - Group 2: four digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\1, \2` - The replacement is: Group 1, `,`, space and Group 2 value.

Answer (score 2):

Just capture the last four digits of each line and delete any preceding digits:

```sh
$ sed 's/[0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1/' input.txt
John, 4567
Bob, 9211
Alex, 7821
Mary, 1281
```

If using a version of `sed` that supports POSIX Extended Regular Expressions, it can be cleaned up a bit to

```sh
sed -E 's/[0-9]*([0-9]{4})$/\1/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {$2=substr($2,length($2)-3)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                          ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=", "                   ##Setting FS and OFS to comma space here.
}
{
  $2=substr($2,length($2)-3)    ##Getting last 4 digits now in 2nd field here.
}
1                               ##printing current edited/non-edited line.
' Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding 1 more solution in case your 2nd column can have mix of digits and other non digits then following may help you.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$2);$2=substr($2,length($2)-3)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                         ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=", "                  ##Setting FS and OFS to comma space here.
}
{
  gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$2)        ##Globally substituting everything apart from digits with NULL in 2nd field.
  $2=substr($2,length($2)-3)   ##getting last 4 digits now in 2nd field here.
}
1                              ##printing current edited/non-edited line.
' Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to KamilCuk's answer except uses a POSIX character class and anchors the digits to be removed:

```
sed  's/, [[:digit:]]\{3\}/, /'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file format is just `<text only alphanumeric characters>, <number exactly 7 digits>`, you can just remove first 3 digits there are:

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9]//'
```

Comment: This regex can be shorted to `sed  's/[0-9]\{3\}//'`